# Additional Folder Icons

Tags: 14.04, icons

Does anyone know of any additional folder icons, in the default style with additional images upon them, to use in Ubuntu?

I would like to customise some of those I have created in my home folder but don't want to deviate from the standard theme.

I also don't want to spend hours making new icons myself if someone else has already gone along that path.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **folder-colors**, a Nautilus extension which enables you to add a color shade to a specific folder. The same folder icon but just in different colors.

Here’s the PPA which you should add to your system repositories through a terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costales/folder-color`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install folder-color`

More information on [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/change-folder-icon-color-ubuntu-linux-easily)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at all application icons you have at your system, here:

`nautilus /usr/share/app-install/icons/`

also at

http://www.iconarchive.com/tag/ubuntu-folder

Comment: Sadly none of those do the trick.  I want some additional folder icons that look like those which come with Ubuntu 'out of the box'.  Thank you for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to change icons on folders I drag and drop on top task bar in Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome (I think).

Open the icon folder on your computer by using the details above in a terminal; nautilus /usr/share/app-install/icons/

Copy icon you like - right click folder icon you want to change - properties - click folder icon in "Launcher Properties" - paste copied icon details into Location box - click open.

Hopefully folder icon will change.

I have not tried this on any other folder icons i.e. on desktop etc